# Unexpected printing issues with Laserjet Enterprise m607; upside down and out of margin printing

Tags: drivers, printing, printer, network-printer

We have a printer (Laserjet Enterprise m607) that has been giving us some weird problems the last few days.

The printer usually prints checks and the two people that print them started having problems with the checks printing outside of the margins about two days ago (both on two separate Windows 10 computers).

I reinstalled the printer on both computers with the exact driver from HP and also reset the printer to default settings and the problem was fixed for the time being. This morning, one person now has the checks printing upside down.

This seems to be a constant problem for the last 3 days with different problems popping up. This is what we know for sure:

- Both computers have the exact HP printer driver installed.
- Both computers run the same OS (Windows 10).
- Both computers are printing from the same program (Jenzabar One).
- Both people using the computers are very experienced in their jobs(10+ years; They know how to print checks and check their print settings).

Here are the things we have already done.

- Reinstalled printers with exact HP printer driver.
- Factory reset printer to factory settings.
- Checked all printer preferences and properties.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the print jobs are plain text with control/escape codes, I would print to a file but still using the printer driver.if you caoture good and bad jobs, you can compare control codes via a search with a text editor. That would help determine if the problem is with the data being sent or further down line...

Comment: I will see if I can compare the control codes between the good and bad print jobs.  I will post an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

"I reinstalled the printer". Did you just delete the printer and reinstall? That will not do the job. Here's how to reinstall an HP printer.

First go to Devices & Printers. Delete the printer. Now go to Control Panel or Settings and uninstall any software relating to the printer. Next, go back to Devices & Printers, click on any other printer and select Print Server Properties from the menu that appears. Click the Drivers tab and remove any instances of the printer.

Then reinstall from a freshly downloaded driver.

Comment: We did delete the printer before reinstalling again.  We reinstalled with the exact driver from HP instead of the universal pcl 6 driver that we usually use.  This fixed the problem with printing outside of the margins.  Then the next day, one of the computers started printing the checks upside down while the other printed right side up.  We are starting to wonder if it is a bug within the program they are printing from(Jenzabar One).

Comment: I did notice that the printer's firmware is not up to date.  Could this be a possible cause for problems like this?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if f/w caused it. It is read-only, it does not change with use. Only update f/w if the release notes say it will fix the problem. This is especially true in the case of HP as they are notorious for adding restrictions (e.g. 3rd party toner) to new f/w.